# Is it possible to read the same pipe twice in bash?

Tags: bash, pipe

Here is my code:

```
ls | grep -E '^application--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz$' | awk '{if($1<"application--'"${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}"'.tar.gz") print $1}' | xargs -r echo
ls | grep -E '^application--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz$' | awk '{if($1<"application--'"${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}"'.tar.gz") print $1}' | xargs -r rm
```

As you can see it will get a list of files, show it on screen (for logging purpose) and then delete it.
The issue is that if a file was created between first and second line gets executed, I will delete a file without logging that fact.

Is there a way to create a script that will read the same pipe twice, so the awk result will be piped to both `xargs echo` and `xargs rm` commands?

I know I can use a file as a temporary buffer, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: When `${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}` always is before today, can you have new files between both statements?

Comment: Can you use `find` with a combination of `-print` and `-exec` ?

Comment: Not out of the box, but if you need this often, you could create a tool which acts as wrapper process. This tool could create two child processes (based on its input parameters), reads its standard input and sends  this to both child processes.

Comment: When you want the output of the first line in a logfile, you can have `awk` write the logging to the logfile and use stdout for the `xargs rm`.

Comment: Didn't try it, but maybe something like `command1 | tee >(command2) | command3` could work: It has only one pipe (fed by command1) and sends its data to both command2 and command 3.

Comment: As an aside, see also [useless use of `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep) which also has a section about useless `ls`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for additional reasons to avoid `ls`.

Comment: Actually, @WalterA you are correct, I didn't think about it this way.
I was thinking that a file might have been created exactly 1 month ago to the second, but I am actually calculating the date once and reusing the date variable, it so in my use case it will never happen. Question might be helpful for other use cases, but for my use case your answer actually solved it.

Comment: Side note: [Do not parse output from `ls`.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead) As for your question: `tee` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, you don't need to read the pipe twice, you can just use `rm -v` to have `rm` itself also "echo" each file.

Also, in cases like this, it is better for shell scripts to use globs instead `grep ...`, both for robustness and performance reasons.

And once you do that, even better: you can loop on the glob and not go through any pipes at all (even more robust in the general case, because there are even less places to worry "could a character in this be special to that program?", and might perform better because everything stays in one process):

```bash
for file in application--[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].tar.gz
do
    if [[ "$file" < "application--${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}.tar.gz" ]]
    then
        # echo "$file"
        # rm "$file"
        rm -v "$file"
    fi
done
```

But if you find yourself in a situation where you really do need to get data from a pipe and a glob won't work, there are a couple ways:

One neat trick in the shell is that loops and other compound commands can be pipes - so *a loop can read a pipe*, and the inside of the loop can have all the commands you wanted to have read from the pipe:

```bash
ls ... | awk ... | while IFS="" read -r file
do
    # echo "$file"
    # rm "$file"
    rm -v "$file"
done
```

(As a general best practice, you'd want to set `IFS=` to the empty string for the `read` command so that `read` doesn't split the input on characters like spaces, and give `read` the `-r` argument to tell it to not interpret special characters like backslashes. In your specific case it doesn't matter.)

But if a loop doesn't work for what you need, then in the general case, you can catch the result of a pipe in a shell variable:

```bash
pipe_contents="$(ls application--[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].tar.gz | awk '{if($1<"application--'"${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}"'.tar.gz") print $1}')"

echo "$pipe_contents"
rm $pipe_contents
```

(This works fine unless your pipe output contains characters that would be special to the shell at the point that the pipe output has to be unquoted - in this case, it needs to be unquoted for the `rm`, because if it's quoted then the shell won't split the captured pipe output on whitespace, and `rm` will end up looking for one big file name that looks like the entire pipe output. Part of why looping on a glob is more robust is that it doesn't have these kinds of problems: the pipe combines all file names into one big text that needs to be re-split on whitespace. Luckily in your case, your file names don't have whitespace nor globbing characters, so leaving the pipe output unquoted ends up being fine.)

Also, since you're using `bash` and your pipe data is multiple separate things, you can use an array variable (bash extension, also found in shells like `zsh`) instead of a regular variable:

```bash
files=($(ls application--[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].tar.gz | awk '{if($1<"application--'"${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}"'.tar.gz") print $1}'))

echo "${files[@]}"
rm "${files[@]}"
```

(Note that an *unquoted* expansion still happens with the array, it just happens when defining the array instead of when passing the pipe contents to `rm`. A small advantage is that if you had multiple commands which needed the unquoted contents, using an array does the splitting only once. A big advantage is that once you recognize array syntax, it does a better job of expressing your big-picture intent through the code itself.)

You can also use a temporary file instead of a shell variable, but you said you want to avoid that. I also prefer a variable when the data fits in memory because Linux/UNIX does not give shell scripts a *reliable* way to clean up external resources (you can use `trap` but for example traps can't run on uncatchable signals).

P.S. ideally, in the general habit, you should use `printf '%s\n' "$foo"` instead of `echo "$foo"`, because `echo` has various special cases (and portability inconsistencies, but that doesn't matter as much if you always use `bash` until you need to care about portable `sh`). In modern featureful shells like `bash`, you can also use `%q` instead of `%s` in `printf`, which is great because for example `printf '%q\n' "${files[@]}"` will actually print each file with any special characters properly quoted or escaped, which can help with debugging if you ever are dealing with files that have special whitespace or globbing characters in them.

Comment: Did you forget an `echo` in the `pipe_contents=` assignments?

Comment: @tripleee oops, I sure did! Or rather, I lost it during some overbroad select-text-then-paste. Great catch, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can change your command to something like

```
touch example
ls example* | tee >(xargs rm)
```

I would prefer to avoid parsing `ls`:

```
while IFS= read -r file; do
  if [[ "$1" < "application--${CLEAR_DATE_LEVEL0}.tar.gz" ]]; then
    echo "Removing ${file}"
    rm "${file}" 
  fi
done < <(find . -regextype egrep -regex "./application--[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}.tar.gz")
```

EDIT: An improvement:
As @tripleee mentioned is their answer, using `rm -v` avoids the additional echo and will also avoid an `echo` when removing a file failed.

Comment: No need to pipe from `find` into a `read` loop when a glob is enough: `for file in application--[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].tar.gz; do ...`.

Comment: Also if you're using `regex` with `find` then you might get false matches unless you escape `.` characters (unless `find` has its own unique slightly incompatible regex, which I doubt), since `.` is the regex wildcard for any character, so `./` would also match any single-character directory like `a/`, and for example `rock.tar.gz` might match `rockstar.gz`, and so on.

Comment: @mtraceur The `for` command is nice, but I wanted to have the same regex as the OP has used (including `{4}` and the unescaped dots). The `./` will not match `a/`, because the output of `find .` will always start with `./`.

Comment: Makes sense re: matching OP's regex and good catch re: the output of `find` always starting with `./`.

Answer (score 0):

No, a pipe is a stream - once you read something from it, it is forever gone from the pipe.

A good general solution is to use a temporary file; this lets you rewind and replay it. Just take care to remove it when you're done.

```
temp=$(mktemp -t) || exit
trap 'rm -f "$temp"' ERR EXIT
cat >"$temp"

cat "$temp"
xargs rm <"$temp"
```

The `ERR` and `EXIT` pseudo-signals are Bash extensions. For POSIX portability, you need a somewhat more involved set of `trap` commands.

Properly speaking, `mktemp` should receive an argument which is used as a template for the temporary file's name, so that the user can see which temporary file belongs to which tool. For example, if this script was called `rmsponge`, you could use `mktemp rmspongeXXXXXXXXX` to have `mktemp` generate a temporary file name which begins with `rmsponge`.

If you only expect a limited amount of input, perhaps just capture the input in a variable. However, this scales poorly, and could have rather unfortunate problems if the input data exceeds available memory;

```
# XXX avoid: scales poorly
values=$(cat)
xargs printf "%s\n" <<<"$values"
xargs rm <<<"$values"
```

The `<<<` "here string" syntax is also a Bash extension. This also suffers from the various issues from https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020 but this is inherent to your problem articulation.

Of course, in this individual case, just use `rm -v` to see which files `rm` removes.

Comment: You can catch the contents in a variable instead of a temporary file - if you expect the data to not be huge, this can be nicer in that it will never hit any of the issues that temporary file cleanup can have.

Comment: Tips: re: mktemp: a temp file should normally start its name with something that makes it clear what program it was made by (for example, by giving `mktemp` a pattern like `my-app-XXXXXX`).

Comment: @mtraceur Could you provide an example of piping into and from a variable as an answer? I expect the from would be simple `echo "$VAR" | other_commands` but what about piping into a variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "piping into a variable"? The answer already demonstrates the use of `cmd | variable=$(cat)` though of course in isolation that does not work.

Comment: @HubertNNN yep, was already working on a comprehensive answer, just finished a few minutes ago.